# Moving to England advice - EU husband, Aussie wife, US child :)

Tags: united-kingdom

Just looking for a little clarity, as the internet has us a tad confused. Thanks in advance :)

We are a family currently living in the US (both green card holders). I'm an Australian passport holder. My husband is an EU (Sweden) holder. Our son (2 years) US holder. 
We are relocating to England for personal reasons (not work) and are looking for clarity on requirements for Mother and Son (Aussie & US) to enter legally and Mum to work.

Firstly, am I right in understanding that none of us require visas to enter? And once in the country I (Aussie) can legally work due to husbands EU status? Are we missing something?

Thanks for your help in clarifying!

Nat :)

Comment: This belongs on [Expatriates.SE], but you should be aware that your son is likely a triple citizen, and since one of those probable citizenships is an EU country you should establish that definitively before moving.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I didn't realize there was an Expatriates page, I will continue over there. Thanks so much :)

Comment: You are missing Brexit. The rules right now differ strongly from the likely rules five months from now, and it is extremely unclear how rules will change in between.

Comment: Ha!  It looks like you asked on Travel, were pointed at  Expat by phoog, asked the question again on Expat, and *then* had the original question migrated to Expat - thus creating a duplicate.  I think closing this one as the duplicate is the right thing - given there is a good answer on the other one already.

Comment: Please note that the UK is quite likely to leave the EU on March 29th, 2019. You will likely be able to enter the UK with your family until end of 2020 (but no guarantees today), and nobody knows exactly whether you can stay from 2021 onward. Moving to the Republic of Ireland, or Germany, France etc., would avoid these problems.